# Limited Type as a passing parameter in Dart linting

Tags: dart, abstraction

I want to make use of the static type benefits of dart and limit incoming Type of a function to specific classes.
As time of writing I have not thought of a design to achieve that (if it is even possible).

Wish:

```
abstract class UpperClass {}

class Class1 extends UpperClass {}

class Class2 extends UpperClass {}

class Class3 {}

void justAcceptSpecific(Type type) => print("doesn't matter");

void main() {
  justAcceptSpecific(Class2); // works
  justAcceptSpecific(Class3); // linting should show wrong type
  justAcceptSpecific(2); // error like here
}
```

I thought about using an abstract class, but the issue is, that I do not want to pass an object, but just the type.

This would work as intended (but it passes the object :/ ):

```
abstract class UpperClass {}

class Class1 extends UpperClass {}

class Class2 extends UpperClass {}

class Class3 {}

void justAcceptSpecific(UpperClass type) => print("doesn't matter");

void main() {
  justAcceptSpecific(Class2());
  justAcceptSpecific(Class3()); // linting shows wrong type, which is like it should be
}
```

If that is of relevance, I intend to use it in a constructor and just made my examples here as function calls for simplicity sake.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing that in Dart would require runtime checks. Why do you want to pass a type?  What do you want `justAcceptSpecific` to ultimately do?  You usually can't do much with a `Type` in Dart.

Comment: I expected as much as I found out the limitations of dar:mirros. 
I have a generic Filter class, that should accept one of three classes, that later evaluate if another parameter (filter field) exists in the class.
The reason for this is, that I do not want to build an individual filter class for each of the three classes